# Uber API /v1/requests end_latitude and end_longitude are not working

Tags: uber-api

I'm using Uber's /v1/requests (https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1/requests-post) API and trying to reserve a ride with end_latitude and end_longitude filled up.

I'm successfully able to book the ride, however, Uber is booking ride without including end location. When I open the Uber App the destination is missing. Here's my api request:

```
debug: APIRequest 
payment_method_id=bb066422-573f-49d1-8eb0-3bedacae44ae, 
product_id=6450cc0f-4d39-4473-8632-1e2c2049fefe, 
start_latitude=47.57298189999999, 
start_longitude=-122.3779403, 
surge_confirmation_id=null, 
end_latitude=47.6173975, 
end_longitude=-122.1317191, 
method=POST, 
uri=https://api.uber.com/v1/requests
```

Could you help please?

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your problem and successfully tested booking a ride through the API with destination filled in. I also see a number of requests in our logs for both v1 & v1.2 from partners where this is happening correctly and I have not heard any complaints about destination dropping from any of our big partners. Although I cannot say this definitively, I would guess there is there is something incorrect in how you are formulating your request. You might want to pass along the curl to further debug. You could also try v1.2 of the API to see if that helps. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. This seemed like a bug in Uber API, I contacted them and they confirmed that they will fix it in a few days. After they fixed it, things were normal and API started working.

Comment: Ok-- interesting! Glad it worked out for you. I work on the Uber API and am not aware of a bug related to this question that was fixed but maybe missed something. Glad it is all working for you now.